# How can I set importmap in a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, import-maps

I can set the importmap type in a  tag in the HTML file. But the web worker can not set access a dom element. How can I set importmap in it?

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/import-maps/issues/2

Comment: @Kaiido I do see that they are discussing possible solutions, but I did not see a solution today. The proposed is a quick-fix to enable the importmap for workers at the moment until a longterm solution is found.
For us the provided solution enables to run three.js in a worker in the background, as three requires importmap operations

Answer (score 2):

We have done the approach by a small bypass via the ES shims (based on the [example](https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims/issues/206) posted on 4th Nov 2022).
Basically you start a worker, enable the worker by es shims to load modules and read these.

We use the item to run a raycaster on a three.js scene which is not visible, but should work generally.

workermanager.js:

```
let worker = new Worker('./workerloader.js');

worker.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
    console.error("the worker died");
    console.error(e);
})

worker.addEventListener("message", function(evt) {
    let result = evt.data;

    if (result === "loaded loader"){
         console.log("loaded the workerloaded");
    } else if (result === "Module worker Loaded")
        worker.postMessage("Init Message");
    else
        console.log(`message from worker: `, evt);
});
```

workerloader.js

```
const shimCodeUrl = "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.2/dist/es-module-shims.wasm.js"

const importMap = {
    "imports": {
        "three":"/whatever_path/three/build/three.module.js",
        "three/":"/whatever_path/three/"
    }
}

postMessage("loaded loader");
importScripts(shimCodeUrl);
importShim.addImportMap(importMap);
importShim("./worker.module.js") /*controllerworker.module.js*/
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("module has been loaded");
    })
    .catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }));
```

worker.module.js:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

class WorkerClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,2));
    }

    onMessage(event)
    {
        console.log(event.data);
    }
}

let workerclass = new WorkerClass();
self.addEventListener("message", evt => workerclass.onMessage(evt));
self.postMessage("Module worker Loaded");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you hsc for posting your answer. You helped me out a ton. Second, I just wanted to add one small thing that might make life easier for some folks.

I have basically the same structure, except that I am wrapping the import code in an event listener.

```js
// WebWorkerLoader.js
const shimCodeUrl = "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.2/dist/es-module-shims.wasm.js"

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if(e.data.type && e.data.type === 'init'){
        const importMapString = e.data.data;
        const importMap = JSON.parse(importMapString);
        importScripts(shimCodeUrl);
        importShim.addImportMap(importMap);

        importShim("./webworker.js") /*controllerworker.module.js*/
            .then(() => {
                console.log("module has been loaded");
            })
            .catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }));
    }
});
```

Then on my main thread script I am fetching my import map that I am already using and passing it on to the webworker. This is handy if you are looking for a quick means to ensure that both the webworker and the main thread have access to the same imports.

```js
if (window.Worker) {
      const webWorker = new Worker('pathToWebWorkerLoader');
      const importMap = document.querySelector('script[type="importmap"]');
      if (importMap) {
                webWorker.postMessage({type: 'init', data: importMap.textContent});
      }
}
```